# WPF: How to autoreset/autorefresh the textbox after scanning barcode in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, barcode

I'm making a simple WPF program where the user will basically only need to scan the barcode using a USB barcode scanner and the program will send the data straight to the cloud ERP. Right now, the program works, but the user has to manually click the textbox after scanning, clear the data and scan again. I just want the user to open the software and just keep on scanning using his barcode reader without having to manually erase the textbox data. How can I do that?

```
<Window x:Class="ProductionScanner.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ProductionScanner.MVVM.ViewModel"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProductionScanner"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    Background="#181735" >

<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:ReceiptViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Background="#0F0F2D"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
         
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Foods"
                   Foreground="White"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   />
        <TextBlock Text="Records"
                   Foreground="White"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   />
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtIniFocus}">

        <TextBox x:Name="txtIniFocus" Margin="6" Text="{Binding Barcode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Grid.Row="1" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged">
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding ReceiptCommand}" />
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
        </TextBox>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

And, the ReceiptViewModel.cs:

```
using ProductionScanner.Cores;
using ProductionScanner.MVVM.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace ProductionScanner.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    public class ReceiptViewModel: ObservableObject
    {
        private string _barcode;

        public string Barcode
        {
            get { return _barcode; }
            set { _barcode = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public RelayCommand ReceiptCommand { get; set; }
        public ReceiptViewModel()
        {
            ReceiptCommand = new RelayCommand(x =>
            {
                receiptInventory();
            });
        }

    private void receiptInventory()
    {
        if (Barcode.Length == 12)
        {
            var inventoryIDFrom = Barcode.Substring(0, 6);
            var kgIntFrom = Barcode.Substring(6);
            var kgDecimalFrom = kgIntFrom.Substring(0,kgIntFrom.Length-4) + "." + kgIntFrom.Substring(kgIntFrom.Length - 4, 3);
            ERPRestService _erpRestService = new ERPRestService();
            ReceiptItems receiptItems = new ReceiptItems();
            receiptItems.InventoryID = inventoryIDFrom;
            receiptItems.Qty = Convert.ToDecimal(kgDecimalFrom);
            receiptItems.WarehouseID = "WH001";
            receiptItems.LocationID = "L001";
            receiptItems.LotSerialNbr = "";
            receiptItems.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {
                var jsonObj1 = new
                {
                    Description = new
                    {
                        value = "Receipt"
                    },
                    Hold = new
                    {
                        value = false
                    },
                    Details = new[]
                    {
                    new {
                        InventoryID = new
                        {
                            value = receiptItems.InventoryID
                        },
                        Qty = new
                        {
                            value = receiptItems.Qty
                        },
                        WarehouseID = new
                        {
                            value = receiptItems.WarehouseID
                        },
                        Location = new
                        {
                            value = receiptItems.LocationID
                        }
                    }
                }

                };
                string entityAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj1);
                //string parameters1 = "$expand=Details";
                var receipt = _erpRestService.Put("InventoryReceipt", null, entityAsString);
                string refRelease = JObject.Parse(receipt)["ReferenceNbr"]["value"].ToString();
                var release = new
                {
                    entity = new
                    {
                        ReferenceNbr = new
                        {
                            value = refRelease
                        }
                    }
                };
                string jsonRelease = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(release);
                jsonRelease = _erpRestService.Post("InventoryReceipt", "ReleaseInventoryReceipt", jsonRelease);
                MessageBox.Show("Your AR Confirm has completed.", "Confirm", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }

            
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                _erpRestService.Dispose();

                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you not just do `Barcode = string.Empty` after the message box? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RyanThomas I tried it before, it didn't work :(

Comment: Is your binding between the TextBox and property definitely working correctly? I noticed there is also a TextChanged event on this box, what does it do?

Comment: The messagebox will take focus.  You should lose that. Show your message in a textblock instead.

Comment: Since you have UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged you could check whether you have 12 characters in the textbox and print your receipt if you do. Lose the command.  I think if you retain focus in the textbox then setting Barcode to string.empty would then allow you to scan into it again. Once it loses focus then you're not going to get your next code scanned into it.

Comment: I'd also be inclined to pass the barcode data into a Task and run that on a background thread as well.

Comment: Is there some other UI you've not shown us?  The textbox is in a stackpanel which seems unnecessary.  I'm also curious what is in TextBox_TextChanged. That will fire per letter and when a blank string transfers from the viewmodel to textbox.

Comment: If the XAML posted is the XAML you actually work with, the binding should function, because you're setting the data context directly in XAML to that viewmodel that exposes BarCode and ReceiptCommand. The only candidate for causing the confusion also I can see seems the `TextChanged` callback, as already mentioned. Do you re-instantiate the VM in here? Or do you manually assign `txtIniFocus.Text` to `BarCode`?
The `OnPropertyChanged` method in ObservableObject should not be broken, otherwise all your UI-target updating on vm prop changed would fail ...

Comment: The text property of a textbox is mode twoway by default. That means setting the text property in code behind would not over write the binding @lidqy.  I think focus is the most obvious first thing to check here. Is there a cursor visible in txtIniFocus after the first scan and receipt?

Comment: @RyanThomas I found an error in the barcode printer that wasn't letting Barcode = string.Empty work. Ultimately, that's what I ended up using. Thank you))

Comment: @Andy I took the messagebox out. II was supposed to take it out before I posted here, but thanks for noticing and reminding! And yes, the program is working now!

Comment: @Andy and RyanThomas the TextChanged  box wasn't implemented properly. I took it out. Code works fine without it too!  And about the stackpanel, I was using just a simple textbox first, but I needed to implement autofocus. I came across a solution that uses stackpanel or dockpanel, hence, stackpanel.

Comment: @lidqy the TextChanged wasn't implemented properly, but I got my problem solved by changing my barcode format and goin with Ryan Thomas's original Barcode = string.Empty solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a simplified version of the markup and code.
The messagebox looked a bit suspicious to me as I was thinking it might take focus. What might happen after that.

Use of return was also a concern as I wondered what else return might do.

There's nowhere else for the focus to go.

If I just press tab then the cursor is still in the textbox.

My experimental markup:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Background="#0F0F2D"
      Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Foods"
               Foreground="White"
               Grid.Column="1"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               />
        <TextBlock Text="Records"
               Foreground="White"
               Grid.Column="2"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               />
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtIniFocus}">
            <TextBox x:Name="txtIniFocus" Margin="6" Text="{Binding Barcode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Grid.Row="1">
                <TextBox.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding ReceiptCommand}" />
                </TextBox.InputBindings>
            </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

My viewmodel

```
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string barcode = "65765765";

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task Receipt()
    {
        // Your receipt processing would go here
        MessageBox.Show("Your AR Confirm has completed.", "Confirm", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        Barcode=string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I hit enter, the messagebox shows. I click OK. The messagebox closes, textbox is empty and the cursor is in the textbox.

If what you've shown us was all you have then I think setting Barcode to string.Empty would probably work.

Not sure it'd make much difference but my property changed notification is from the community toolkit mvvm and using the code generator. It  will check for equality before raising property changed.

I'm not sure what your observableobject is there.

I still think the messagebox is a bad idea as the user has to pick the mouse up and click. An on screen indicator would be something to consider instead.

FWIW

I would also recommend just checking the length is 12 and drive the processing that way.

If you do both then the user could just scan, the receipt is done, scan the next receipt is done, scan....

They wouldn't have to touch keyboard or mouse.

That's the approach I've used for warehouse and product scanning on what sound like similar apps.

Comment: Hi! As you and @RyanThomas originally suggested, Barcode = string.Empty did work! I had a problem with the barcode printer's barcode format, which was also linked to the ERP. I fixed it, and now the program is working properly. Thank you for your valuable inputs and suggestions)) Really appreciate it!